# Data Flow Task: Processa, mas não grava no Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Estou utilizando o SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) com o SQL Server Data Tools (componente gráfico para o Visual Studio 2015).

Dentro do meu pacote de processamento (SSIS) tenho fluxos que, dependendo da condição definida o respectivo Data Flow Task é acionado.

Cada Data Flow Task tem basicamente um Flat File Source usando o ADO.Net Source e um Script Component, onde faço os tratamentos usando a linguagem C#.

O processamento fica em Loop, e basicamente faz o seguinte:
Se for arquivo 1, vá para Data Flow Task 1 (vide imagem abaixo);
[image: Processamento 01]

Se for arquivo 2, vá para Data Flow Task 2 (vide imagem abaixo);
[image: Processamento 02]

Em todos os casos deveriam ser inseridos na mesma tabela, mas com tratamentos diferentes devido as regra de negócio.

Entretanto, é aonde estou com problema. Não apresenta erro no fluxo, Descrevendo melhor.

No caso 1, os dados são inseridos corretamente depois de validadas todas as regras (vide imagem abaixo);
[image: Evidência do Processamento 01]

No caso 2, os dados não inseridos no banco de dados, mesmo depois de validadas as regras (vide imagem abaixo)
[image: Evidência do Processamento 02]

**Um adendo importante:**
Se eu excluir ou desabilitar o primeiro Data Flow Task, e mandar executar de novo o pacote o segundo Data Flow Task (a segunda tarefa) processa normalmente.

Já verifiquei a codificação e não há erros, criei até do zero tudo de novo, mas nada funcionou; Tentei encontrar até algum cache ou referência que estivesse errada, mas nada foi detectado de errado.

Então, alguém depois de entender todo este processo saberia me dizer o que está ocorrendo?

Grato pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Tentei também ajustar colocando todos dentro de um mesmo **Data Flow Task**, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Tentei outra abordagem também colocando cada **Data Flow Task** dentro de um **Sequence Container** também não funcionou. Todas as demais Tacks continuam funcionando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se seu componente de fluxo de dados está configurado para "redirecionar linha".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso esteja tente mudar para "falha no componente".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao mudar a configuração para "falha no componente" e executar, caso de erro, você pode ir em processo e ver as mensagens de erro que podem te ajudar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]